# dotnetbrowser - chromium version upgrades

Tags: dotnetbrowser

I am evaluating embedded Chromium browser for .NET app and close to making decision on dotnetbrowser. the only catch is that it is built of Chromium 64. Does anyone know the frequencies of Chromium uplift that is done by dotnetbrowser? I don't want to get to a situation where my customers are holding onto an old version that may end up having security vulnerabilities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DotNetBrowser upgrades up to the stable Chromium build 2-3 times a year depending on the number of fixes/changes/improvements in the latest Chromium update.